# Three js black color of material to transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to make Lambert material from texture with transparent black color without alphaMap.

I have sphere with clouds texture. I need to be black color transparent, if i use blending, it have affect on shadow, i need keep behavior like MeshPhong material, but only with transparent black color.

```
var cloudsMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { 
                        color: 0xffffff, 
                        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/clouds.jpg" ),

                        specular   : new THREE.Color("rgb(255,255,255)"),
                        shininess  : 0.1,                              
                        depthTest  : 0,
                        blending   : 1,
                        transparent: true,
                        bumpScale  : 1, //0.8
                        bumpMap    : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/bump.jpg" ),                                                      
                        } );
```

what is the correct way, to setup blending, or another attributes?

Comment: Try `blending:2` or `blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending`. Blending mode constants are [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Constants/Materials)

Comment: additive blending will make texture ... additive. Im experimenting with custom blending, no combination did the trick. I need to make only renderer clear color transparent (black) and other colors as they is, if is color at pixel gray (50% black) there should be 50% transparency. I cant use Alpha Map, because is it custom animated shader and alphaMap is not animated.

Comment: There are ways to do it, for example defining a custom shader, but it seems the easiest is to just add alpha channel to your texture. If you can't modify the resources you can do it runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me was to use a alpha map (BW texture where white = less opacity, black = 100% opaque):

```
var t = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "clouds.jpg" );
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "clouds_alpha.jpg" );
var cloudsMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { 
                        map        : t,
                        alphaMap   : map,
                        blending   : 1,
                        transparent: true,                                                    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be done. Blend a jpg with black bg transparent. Martin, alphaMap:map is undefined. This question doesn't seem to be answered.

if I remember right, its glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
I am sure Threejs didnt ignore it.

Comment: black = 100% opaque = not transparent. seems the reverse the intended result.